# Get CheckBoxList descriptions from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

I want to put a checkboxlist in my aspx page that gets value descriptions from a table in the database.
For example, I have this table:

```
Descriptions

1 - Description1
2 - Description2
3 - Description3
4 - Description4
5 - Description5
...
```

and I should obtain a list of checkboxes like this:

```
X - Description1
X - Description2
....
```

How can I make this?

Thanks in advance.

Luigi

Answer (score 3):

I put out a blog post on this. I hope it helps:

http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2008/10/12/Bind-CheckBoxList-to-DataSet.aspx

Comment: Thank you, it seems perfect for my scope.

Luigi